# Multiple if statements are executing in succesion?

Tags: javascript

I have many if statements the are supposed to trigger on a left or right key press. But when I hit left, it just executes the left key press on all the if statements, even though there are conditons for each statement.

```
var currentBranch = 1;


if ((currentBranch == 1) && (keyPressed[key.left] == true)){
        background.image.src = treeStructure[0][0];
        currentBranch = 3;  
        console.log(currentBranch);         
    } else if ((currentBranch == 1) && (keyPressed[key.right] == true)) {
        background.image.src = treeStructure[0][1];
        currentBranch = 2;
        console.log(currentBranch);
    }       
    if ((currentBranch == 3) && (keyPressed[key.left] == true)){
        background.image.src = treeStructure[1][0];
        currentBranch = 4;
        console.log(currentBranch);
    } else if ((currentBranch == 3) && (keyPressed[key.right] == true)) {
        background.image.src = treeStructure[1][1];
        currentBranch = 9;
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(currentBranch);
    }
    if ((currentBranch == 4) && (keyPressed[key.left] == true)){
        background.image.src = treeStructure[2][0];
        currentBranch = 6;
        console.log(currentBranch);
    } else if ((currentBranch == 4) && (keyPressed[key.right] == true)) {
        background.image.src = treeStructure[2][1];
        currentBranch = 5;
```

Shouldn't the currentBranch variable stop it after each if statement, for a new key press?

Comment: You change `currentBranch` inside each `if` branch, thereby making the condition true on the *next* `if`. Maybe you should add a `return` statement inside each `if`? Or change them to `else if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code is actually 3 separate if... else if... blocks, not one set of chained if blocks. This means that their "truthiness" will be evaluated individually, rather than breaking out after one has evaluated to true.

The first "if..." block evaluates to true, and then inside of that block, you set the variable "currentBranch" to 3, which causes the next if block to evaluate to true, and so on down the line.

You need to change the structure of your code to this:

```
if (statement) {
  //code
}
else if (statement) {
  //code
}
else if (statement) {
  //code
}
else if (statement) {
  //code
}
else if (statement) {
  //code
}
else if (statement) {
  //code
}
```

This way, the lower blocks won't be evaluated once a block has evaluated to true.